# вывод числа с плавающей точкой в двоичном виде

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как можно адаптировать такой код для обработки дробных числел с несколькими знаками после точки. К примеру -32.000001230001. Или возможно есть более подходящее решение вместо bitset?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>

int main() {
    long double num = 32;
    std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT>(num) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Что вы хотите делать с веществеными числами в битовом представлении?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу - как вариант:

```
    float a = 32;
    char *s = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
    cout << bitset<8>(s[3]) << endl;
    cout << bitset<8>(s[2]) << endl;
    cout << bitset<8>(s[1]) << endl;
    cout << bitset<8>(s[0]) << endl;
```

Насчет порядка вывода элементов массива char - почитайте little endian. Надеюсь, не написал чепуху и не ввёл никого в заблуждение...